# batch Loop through file in folder

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, batch-processing

all, I'm a newbie with a little knowledge about scripting.
I did this .bat that work perfectly:

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 4) do (
echo %%x
type A%%x.xml + tail.xml >> v%%x.stage
)
```

It does the loops 4 times, merging the xml files inside the folder. The .bat is in the same folder as the xml to merge.

But I need to edit manually the number 4 if I want to perform a loop of 10.
Is there any way to do a loop using the amount of file in the folder?
Let's say there are 15 .xml files in the folder so the loop will run 15 times.
I've tried different loop codes that I've found on stack overflow, but I wasn't able to make them work :( 
can you help me, please?

many thanks

UPDATE:
thanks @Squashman, so my code should be something like this now right?

```
for %%x IN (*.xml) do set /a count+=1
echo %%x
type A%%x.xml + tail.xml >> v%%x.stage
```

Comment: `for %%G IN (*.xml) do set /a count+=1`

Comment: @Squashman i've updated the post with a bit of code, can you help me further, please?

Comment: Use the `FOR` command I gave you above your `FOR` command.  Then use the environmental variable `%count%` where the `4` is in your code.

Comment: it works PERFECTLY, thanks @Squashman :D

Comment: If there are `15` `.xml` files in the directory, there should only be `14` loops, _because `tail.xml` will be one of those and I'm reasonably confident that you don't want to merge it with itself_.

Comment: @Compo Thanks, yes you're right, actually, I'm removing the extra file by hand, (not a big deal..) which edit you suggest in order to loop only 14 times?

Answer (score 0):

If the range of numbers is guarantied to be contiguous, 
Squashman's suggestion will work well.

To get the highest number independent of any possible gaps, you could use:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\12\18\SO_53837368.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Max=0"
For /f "delims=a." %%A in ('Dir /B "a*.xml"') do (
    Set /A "Num=%%A"
    if !Num! gtr !Max! set "Max=!Num!"
)
Echo Max number is: %Max%
```

it splits the filename between the leading a and the dot from the extension keeping the sole number.
The Set /A is used to exclude possible mismatches with nonnueric values.

Comment: thanks @LotPings at now my range of files is contiguous, but in case of different files, I'll keep in mind your code :D

Comment: I think in theory you could use your code and use the `!num!` as part of the copy command. `copy A!num!.xml + tail.xml >> v!num!.stage`.  The problem is we don't know all the specifics of the entire process so it is hard to provide a concrete bullet proof answer.